# Parsed string without u""

Tags: python, string

How can a string be created without `u''` wrapper?
I'm generating some string that I'd like to put into the array.

E.g.

```
STR = ""
for i in some_array:
    STR += '\'\t<img src="media/'+i+'" alt="" />\n,\' '
arr = ['i"m', 'the', 'array', STR, 'end']

# The result is:
# arr = ['i"m', 'the', 'array', u'\'\t<img src="media/1.jpg" alt="" />\n\', \'\t<img src="media/2.jpg" alt="" />\n\' ', 'end']
# i'd like to have it like:
# arr = ['i"m', 'the', 'array', '\t<img src="media/1.jpg" alt="" />\n', '\t<img src="media/2.jpg" alt="" />\n', 'end']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That wrapper is just something indicating in the interactive Python console that it's a `unicode` string. If you print it out or put it in a template (e.g. with `print(' '.join(arr))`), the `u""` won't show up.

Comment: Right up until you have a non-ASCII character. And then your project blows up.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams ...depending on what you're doing with it. Django setups typically work just fine with full unicode.

Comment: `python -c 'print "é"'` works just fine for me. Depends on your terminal / output stream encoding.

Answer (score 2):

That *is* a string. If you want it to be a bytestring then [you'll need to encode it first](http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/).